# com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized when I try to create a google people contact

Tags: servlets, google-api, google-people-api

Good day.

I'm developing a java servlet that allow to add or update a contact on Google Contact.
I've created a Google application having Google People service active.
Before to use the Google People service I made a Google connection (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth) including between other parameters the scope (openid%20email) and the clientid created in the Google application.
Get the access token (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token) and the user id (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo), I use the class GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder passing ClientId, ClientSecret (both read from Google application) and PeopleServiceScopes.CONTACTS as scope.
Then I tryied to instance the Credential class using loadCredential method of GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow obtained before (passing the user id), but is null.
So I use createAndStoreCredential method of GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow passing as parameters the access token and the user idn and I obtained the Credential class.
At this point I've instantiated PeopleService class and the class Person where I put the values obtained from user input.
When I make service.people().createContact(person).execute().getResourceName() in order to create a new contact and obtains the resource name, this error appears:
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
POST https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact

Why?

Best regards.

Stefano Errani

Comment: Please share an extract of the code where you're generating the credentials (redacting sensitive info), the service variable and performing the .execute() call. Also, are you using a service account? It is possible that this is related to the type of authorization you're using and how it is built.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet of code on caller servlet

```
String clientId = "MY-CLIENT_ID";
String scope = "openid%20email";
StringBuilder oauthUrl = new StringBuilder().append("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth")
   .append("?client_id=").append(clientId)
   .append("&response_type=code")
   .append("&scope=" + scope)
   .append("&redirect_uri=" +  OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.getOAuthCodeCallbackHandlerUrl(req, "clipro", yesfilter, idgc, operaz, idage, mdvw, id))
    .append("&state=this_can_be_anything_to_help_correlate_the_response%3Dlike_session_id")
  .append("&access_type=online")
  .append("&approval_prompt=force");
```

The getOAuthCodeCallbackHandlerUrl method set a HttpSession and call OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.
This is the snipped code of the processReuqest of the servlet:

```
String clientId = "MY-CLIENT_ID";
String secredId = "MY-CLIENT_SECRET"; 
String code = request.getParameter("code");
LinkedHashMap<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
params.put("code", code);`enter code here`
params.put("client_id", clientId);
params.put("client_secret", secretId);
params.put("redirect_uri", getRedirectUrl(request));
params.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");
String body = post("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", params);
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
try {
   jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(body);
} catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
   System.err.println("Unable to parse json " + body);
}
String accessToken = (String) jsonObject.get("access_token");
request.getSession().setAttribute("access_token", accessToken);
String scopeUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo";
String json = get(new StringBuilder(scopeUrl + "?access_token=").append(accessToken).toString());
try {
   jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(json);
} catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
   System.err.println("Unable to parse json " + body);
}
String userId = (String) jsonObject.get("id");
List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList(PeopleServiceScopes.CONTACTS);
NetHttpTransport httpTransport = null;
try {
    httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, secretId, scopes).setAccessType("online").build();
Credential credential = flow.loadCredential(userId);
if (credential == null) { /* credential is allways null */
   TokenResponse tkresp = new TokenResponse();
   tkresp.setAccessToken(accessToken);
   flow.createAndStoreCredential(tkresp, userId);
}
PeopleService service = new PeopleService.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,  credential).setApplicationName("ImmobiWeb").build();
/* settings the person's informations */
String idgc = service.people().createContact(person).execute().getResourceName();
```

Those are the get and post method:

```
public String get(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    return execute(new HttpGet(url));
}

public String post(String url, Map<String, String> formParameters) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (String key : formParameters.keySet()) {
      nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, formParameters.get(key)));
    }
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
    return execute(request);
}

private String execute(HttpRequestBase request) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String body = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Expected 200 but got " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ", with body " + body);
    }
    return body;
}
```

This is the error that appears:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
POST https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$3.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:466)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:552)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:493)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:603)
at OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.processRequest(OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.java:339)
at OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.doGet(OAuthCodeCallbackHandlerServlet.java:398)
```

...

Best regards.

Stefano Errani

Comment: In the same servlet I'm tried to create a Google Calendar Event using the same authentication, except the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow scope parameter that is CalendarScopes.CALENDAR, but when I try to make  com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event createdEvent = service.events().insert("primary", event).execute(); the above error appear:
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events

In the Google application also Google Calendar service is active.